# Munin on Ubuntu 16.04 - Empty network graphs

Tags: 16.04, munin

I have a strange issue with munin on Ubuntu 16.04. All the graphs are ok but the network traffic and errors which are empty.

I see nothing in the logs about it, and running:

```
munin-run if_eth0
```

gives the output:

```
down.value 5382101121
up.value 79038417951
```

which seems ok to me. Running if_err_eth0 works too, but the graphs are like this:
[image]

How can I fix this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found what the problem was. Munin was unable to determine the ethernet connection speed, and in the details of the traffic graph it was reporting:

> Maximum speed is -1Mb/s.

I don't know if this issue is global to Ubuntu 16.04, but it was not here on the same cloud instance with prior versions of the OS.

To fix it, I just forced the link speed in the plugin's configuration (/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node):

```
[if_*]
user root
env.speed 1000
```